# Add id to menu items in wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wp_nav_menu in Wordpress to create my navigation

The output is similar to this(I have removed href links)

```
    <nav id="pageNav">
        <ul id="menu-headernav" class="menu">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>         
    </nav>
```

I need to style each link separately.

How can I add an id to each (li) or (a) in the menu so I can style it.

Answer (score 7):

For the `a` tag, you can add an id attribute by writing in function in your theme's function.php file and hook into the `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter.

Check out the WordPress core at:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L89

```
function my_id_attribute ($atts, $item, $args) {
  //develop your anchor tag ID nomenclature I'll call it $id
  $atts['id'] = $id;
  return $atts;
  }
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_id_attribute', 10, 3);
```

For the `li` tag, you can use the `nav_menu_item_id` filter to modify the id attribute.

```
function my_li_id_handler ($id, $item, $args) {
 //the $item variable is a WP_Post instance...handy properties are $item->post_title, $item->post_name and $item->menu_order
 //do your id nomenclature work here.
 return $id;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id','my_li_id_handler', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add a class for each menu item from within wordpress. Go to "Appearance" -->"Menus" --> and then in the screen options panel, click the checkbox to activate "CSS Classes". From there you can assign unique selectors to your menu items for your CSS to target.

Comment: This is the easiest way. Best not to use a hook unless  you really need it.

Comment: This is very useful to know about, but doesn't (currently) allow for setting the `id` attribute as was requested.